# jQuery UI Slider-Pips: Add label to every other pip only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-slider

I need to create a slider that has a label on every other pip using the UI Slider Pips Plugin but so far nothing on the documentation has been able to help me out completely. Could the inrange functionality help me solve this?
I get it to where I have all the pips, including the halves, and all the labels... but want only the round numbers to show, like this:

```
-
-- 10
-
-- 11
-
-- 12
-
```

So far my code:

```js
$("#mySlider")
    .slider({
        max: maxValue,
        min: minValue,
        step: 0.5,
        range: "min",
        value: 11,
        orientation: "vertical",

    })
  
    .slider("pips", {
        rest: 'label'     
    })
    .slider("float", {
        pips: true,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you need is `step: 2`;

```js
.slider("pips", {
    rest: "label",
    step: 2
})
```

It's well documented here; https://simeydotme.github.io/jQuery-ui-Slider-Pips/#example-steps-stacking